# How to generate unique Voucher code in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to save unique voucher code and mix of characters and numerics and it should be 6 in length. I am using Laravel Framework 5.2

```
enter code here
$data = $request->all();
        unset($data['_token']);
        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); die;
        for ($i=1; $i <=$data['countvoucher']; $i++) { 
            $voucher = new Voucher;
            $voucher->code = "123456";// it should be dynamic and unique
            $voucher->percentage = $data['percentage'];
            $voucher->usage  = $data['usage'];
            $voucher->expirydate = $data['expirydate'];
            $voucher->save();
        }
```

**$voucher->code** i want to save in this filed can anyone help me

Comment: use random code for this..

Comment: @kunal you can take a look at examples here https://github.com/rspective/voucher-code-generator-js It's JS but you can easily convert it to PHP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am using this function
 You may use it like something like bellow

```
 $voucher->code = $this->generateRandomString(6);// it should be dynamic and unique 

public  function generateRandomString($length = 20) {
        $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }
        return $randomString;
    }
```

Comment: thank you its working but you have one mistake $voucher->code = $voucher->generateRandomString(6); replace to $voucher->code = $this->generateRandomString(6);

Comment: I like this option because you can exclude "problematic" characters like: l, 1, i, that may be confusing to type.

Comment: Even when it is a random string, it's necessary to check in the db if the code was generated before, to avoid unexpected behaviors.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the thing that guarantee the uniqueness here

Comment: it's not likely for this function to create a code that is (not unique), especially when $length is large, but as more and more codes get generated, it gets dangerous, so it's not guaranteed

Answer (score 6):

```
  private static function generateNumber()
    {
        $number = Str::random(9);
        if (self::where('number', $number)->count() > 0) self::generateNumber();
        return $number;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Laravel's built-in helper method [`str_random`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-str-random) which generate a more truly "random" alpha-numeric string as:

```
str_random(6)
```

> The `str_random` function generates a random string of the specified length. This function uses PHP's  `random_bytes` function.

So your final code will be as:

```
$voucher->code = str_random(6);
```

Comment: i think if i generate another it doesn't provide uniqueness

Comment: Try it on `tinker` it always generates a unique code. I have tested it.

Comment: tinker ?? means

Comment: In your command line write `php artisan tinker` and then write `str_random(6)` in each new line.

Comment: Read more about it here https://scotch.io/tutorials/tinker-with-the-data-in-your-laravel-apps-with-php-artisan-tinker

Comment: I would suggest you, try it once more in your code as it works perfectly in some of my projects.

Answer (score 1):

Here is this code

```
$chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$code = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $code .= $chars[mt_rand(0, strlen($chars)-1)];
}
```

Replace your this line in your code with

```
$voucher->code = $code;// it should be dynamic and unique
```

I hope this will work

**EDIT**

You can try other ways too

```
$code = strtoupper(uniqid()); // if you dont have any restriction on length of code
```

For length constraint try this

```
function generateCouponCode($length = 6) {
  $chars = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  $ret = '';
  for($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
    $random = str_shuffle($chars);
    $ret .= $random[0];
  }
  return $ret;
}
```

Comment: Add this function in helper and use wherever you want to throughout project

Answer (score 1):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
$random = Str::random(6);
"emPK39"
```